# Concatenate new Iron Router subscriptions to existing ones

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Let's say I have a `RouteController` with a set of subscriptions in `waitOn`. If I create a route based on that controller, is there a good way to say "wait on all of the subscriptions from the controller, but **in addition** subscribe to this".

In other words I want to concatenate to existing `waitOn` subscriptions rather than completely override them. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this approach of using child and parent controllers. You can access the parent call with `__super__`. Here's an example:

```
ParentController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() { 
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe("foo"),
      Meteor.subscribe("bar")
    ] 
  }
})

ChildController = ParentController.extend({
  waitOn: function() { 
    return _.extend(
      ChildController.__super__.waitOn.call(this), [
        Meteor.subscribe("baz"),
        Meteor.subscribe("fiz")
      ]
    )
  }
})
```